# Copy Content of View and make image of it for paste in SMS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I see one application Cartolina card in that when we click on send as Text button the Native SMS application get open in that we can directly paste the card that we have edit.
so i want code that can copy my view as image or anything so i am able to paste that card in SMS application.

AnyOne can help me for copy content of view. as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
```

for paste object in native SMS(`Message`) application.

Comment: But how to paste after launching sms app